Advance Search Option looking for Magento 2 Website
In the market, various Magento plugins are available for the website search option, but I am not sure which is good. We are looking for a Search facility like Wallsandfloors.
Expected behavior
Web searches need to be user-friendly. The result should be relevant to the search and even show suggested terms that are helpful for the user in finding the product. Web searches should reduce user time when it comes to finding a particular product. The search result should be beneficial for the user when deciding to find an appropriate product.

They are using Smile ElasticSuite Basically there frontend is in vuestorefront and backend is in magento. Check out here github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite
